# Combination of 2 data.Frame having different structures

Tags: r, merge

I search an effective method to combine these 2 data.frames :
One with questions and their answers and points associated (questions organized by rows)

```
answer <- data.frame(num_question = c("X01","X02","X03","X04"), 
                     ans = c("A","C","B","C"),
                     point = c(1,2,1,0.5))

num_question ans point
X01          A   1.0
X02          C   2.0
X03          B   1.0
X04          C   0.5
```

and the other with the number of candidat and their answer (questions organized by columns)

```
extract <- data.frame(cand = c("can1","can2","can3"), 
                      X01 = c("A","A","B"),
                      X02 = c("B","C","C"),
                      X03 = c("B","B","B"),
                      X04 = c("C","C","A"))

 cand X01 X02 X03 X04
 can1   A   B   B   C
 can2   A   C   B   C
 can3   B   C   B   A
```

How to reach at the next result ? A data frame with the same dimension than the second one but instead of the answers, we would find the points located in the data frame answer.

Desired output:

```
result_research <- data.frame(cand = c("can1","can2","can3"), 
                              X01 = c(1,1,0),
                              X02 = c(0,2,2),
                              X03 = c(1,1,1),
                              X04 = c(0.5,0.5,0))

   cand X01 X02 X03 X04
   can1   1   0   1 0.5
   can2   1   2   1 0.5
   can3   0   2   1 0.0
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be done with base R using `apply`:

```r
extract[, -1] <- t(apply(extract[, -1], 1, function(x) 
     ifelse(x[match(names(x), answer$num_question)] == answer$ans, answer$point, 0)
    ))

extract
#>   cand X01 X02 X03 X04
#> 1 can1   1   0   1 0.5
#> 2 can2   1   2   1 0.5
#> 3 can3   0   2   1 0.0
```

For each row in `extract` (i.e. each candidate) match the question numbers between data.frames using `match`. If the given answer coincides with the correct answer return the associated point, otherwise return zero.

---

Or without `apply` using only vectorized operations:

```r
answer <- answer[match(answer$num_question, names(extract)[-1]), ]
extract[, -1] <- t((t(extract[, -1]) == answer$ans) * answer$point)

extract
#>   cand X01 X02 X03 X04
#> 1 can1   1   0   1 0.5
#> 2 can2   1   2   1 0.5
#> 3 can3   0   2   1 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

tmp <- extract %>% 
  gather(num_question, can_ans, -cand) %>%  # turn the extract data.frame into long format
  left_join(answer, by="num_question") %>% #merge extract by question number into a single data.frame
  mutate(correct = (can_ans == ans)+0) %>% # is candidate answer the same as the correct answer (1 = TRUE, 0 = FALSE)
  mutate(result = correct*point) # multiply correct answer (1) with points given

#turn the data.frame into wide format
tmp %>% 
  select(cand, num_question, result) %>% 
  spread(num_question,result) 

#   cand X01 X02 X03 X04
# 1 can1   1   0   1 0.5
# 2 can2   1   2   1 0.5
# 3 can3   0   2   1 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R approach with `stack` and `unstack`, i.e.

```
d1 <- stack(extract[-1])
d1$values <- answer$point[match(do.call(paste, d1), paste(answer$ans, answer$num_question))]
d1$values <- replace(d1$values, is.na(d1$values), 0)
cbind.data.frame(cand = extract$cand, unstack(d1))

#  cand X01 X02 X03 X04
#1 can1   1   0   1 0.5
#2 can2   1   2   1 0.5
#3 can3   0   2   1 0.0
```

Comment: Where do I found stack function ? in utils package ?

Comment: It's a base R function

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr) 
library(reshape2) 

dataQA <- melt(extract, id ="cand") %>% #long format for extract
rename(num_question = variable, ans = value) %>% 
left_join(answer) %>% #merge dataframes
mutate(point = ifelse(is.na(point), 0, point)) %>% #wrong answer = 0
select(cand, num_question, point) %>% 
dcast(cand ~ num_question) #back to wide format
```

output :

```
cand X01 X02 X03 X04
1 can1   1   0   1 0.5
2 can2   1   2   1 0.5
3 can3   0   2   1 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dplyr` and `tidyr` to `gather` data to long format, `left_join` on `num_question` and `ans`, replace `NA`s with 0 and `spread` the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

extract %>%
  gather(key, value, -cand) %>%
  left_join(answer, by = c("key" = "num_question", "value" = "ans")) %>%
  replace_na(list(point = 0)) %>%
  select(-value) %>%
  spread(key, point)

#  cand X01 X02 X03 X04
#1 can1   1   0   1 0.5
#2 can2   1   2   1 0.5
#3 can3   0   2   1 0.0
```